# Show Facebook Image likes on website

Tags: facebook

We have a Facebook page full of images, and with these images a lot of 'likes'. What I want to do is to show the image and the amount of likes (and possibly a like button) on our own site. Creating a like button we can do, showing the picture from Facebook we can do. But we cannot find the URL to point the like button at that seems to include / show the like likes from clicking like with the picture in the Facebook album.

Basically what we want is one picture (stored in a Facebook album) and showing the likes in a place outside Facebook, these should be the likes the image gets when people like it on Facebook.

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve this specific URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How have you gone about doing this already?

Have you checked out the Facebook [Open Graph protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)? You can get all the information you need from there.

Here is the Facebook link to the [Like Button social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). There is a configurator on this page that will generate the respective `Like Button` code for you to drop into your page. There are also definitions for the attributes which are created by the configurator - such as `button_count` (number of likes) and `show_faces` (whether to show the faces of people who clicked the like button) - which you can modify as you require.

### --Edit--

Looks like it is a facebook bug:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10674

They have claimed to have fixed it, but people are still reporting the error. I get the error when trying to like your page through the [FB Javascript Test Console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/).

Comment: The issue is not how to create the like button, or a link to the image. The problem is that the link to the image in a like button does not show the likes on the image in Facebook itself. I have tried different url's and such but cannot seem to find it.  I am also digging through the Graph protocol but so far I have not found the answer.

Comment: Do you have a link I can have a look at?

Comment: That is a weird one. It is going on my facebook as a like and a comment - but there is nothing on your picture!

Comment: Well, a bug it is then,although maybe they just like to keep things on facebook and not outside of it <.<. Thanks for the digging, I can see how that makes your head hurt though :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example with an image from coca-cola: https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305

"Link" is what youre looking for.

Comment: The link gives me an image with 817 likes.  If I make a likebutton with this same url it shows 4 likes. So these seem to be different ' likes'  What I am looking for is the url for the like button that will make my like button for the image show those 817 likes.